# Prevent iframe from freezing the main page with an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, infinite-loop, freeze

I execute user-provided javascript code inside iframes. It is possible that the executed code was submitted by a different user, so it needs to be sandboxed as much as possible. The sandbox attribute on the iframe helps a great deal, as does using a Content-Security-Policy for it.

However, I still need a way to prevent malicious code from freezing the website.

I can see two possibilities, but don't know how to get either to work:

1: All code in the iframe is run in a Worker dedicated to that iframe. Unfortunately, the code in the iframe must be allowed to alter the html contained in the iframe. By modifying it so that it loads another script, the code could effectively break itself out of the worker.

2: The code does run in the main thread, but there is a Worker watching over the page. This worker can somehow tell when the website is frozen because of an iframe and then kill only those scripts that are at fault.

Comment: There's no way of telling if the code is just long-running or if it's frozen. Even the venerable JSFiddle.net doesn't detect it: https://jsfiddle.net/acbsgvhu/. You might want to read up on [the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: I know that. What I mean is that if the website is not responsive for at least X seconds, and the reason for that is the iframe, then it gets killed.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that would be to have code in the iframe that pings the parent at a set time interval. You could have the parent, if more than n pings have been missed, kill the iframe. But, since you've (rightly) sandboxed the iframe, it shouldn't be able to communicate with the parent. Also, if the code that's freezing the website is aggressive enough, it would make it so that the parent frame stops running, so the code receiving the pings would fail to run. It would have to be something in the browser itself that does it, like an extension.

Comment: Is the iframe code expected to have complete control over the html in the iframe? If partial control would be acceptable it's not too difficult to send messages from worker to iframe. This code was an attempt of mine to achieve this limited interactivity: https://github.com/loadedsith/survival/blob/master/js/workers/workerLib.js

Comment: Unfortunately, the code in the iframe needs full control.

Comment: I observe that jsfiddle.net manages not to freeze when running an infinite loop.  (At least for me, in Chrome, today.)  Maybe this has something to do with the fact that the iframe is sourced from a different domain, fiddle.jshell.net.